# I am getting this error while uploading a image file

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function upload_image_and_thumbnail() on
>   a non-object in /home/.....

**my code**

```
<?  common::user_access_only("admin");
$q->select()
->from("maincategory")
->run();
$data =  $q->get_selected();

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    validate();
    if(form_validation::validate_fields())
    {
        $title=common::get_control_value("title");

        $descri=common::get_control_value("description");
        $featureimage=common::get_control_value("icon");

       if($_FILES['featureimage']['size']>0)
        {
            $featureimage=$imgfun->upload_image_and_thumbnail('featureimage',120,80,'userfiles','contents',false);
        }
        $q=new Query();
        $q->insert_into("maincategory",array("title"=>$title,"description"=>$descri,"icon"=>$featureimage))
        ->run();
        common::set_message(3);          common::redirect_to(common::get_component_link(array("maincategory","add")));
    }
}?>
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You should define `$imgfun` as an object before trying to use it.

Comment: how to define $imgfun
sorry ,i am new to PHP

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot tell you . The code looks as if it relies on some additional software component, but that is something we cannot guess from here. It is your code, you know the details, we only see what you post. Most likely, by guessing based on the name `$imgfun` this code is meant to work together with some "image fun library" or similar (which I don't know). If you just copied this code from somewhere and don't know what this is about, then sorry, no way for us to help here.